# EntityFramework 6.1.3: The type 'IdentityDbContext<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a project in `net45`. In solution, I have two projects. One is a `MVC webapp` (using EF) and other is a service (using `DBContext` defined in webapp). The strange part is, I can compile my webapp without any problems, but when I *Rebuild* my service project, I get this error:

> The type 'IdentityDbContext<>' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I am referencing same EF version of library as I am in my webapp. Can anybody please tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try a clean?

Comment: Just did that. And then *Rebuild*. Still, no luck.

Comment: Go to the references folder, Alt + F4 on EntityFramwork assembly and check the version.

Comment: Runtime version: v4.0.30319, Version: 6.0.0.0

Comment: That class isn't part of EntityFramework, it's part of Identity.EntityFramework (NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework). Do you have that referenced in your service project?

Comment: @JeffSiver, that solved my problem. Its very confusing what library does what when they have similar names. Thanks a lot. Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @PrakharMishra, Done. And happy I could help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That class isn't part of EntityFramework, it's part of Identity.EntityFrame‌​work (NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Ide‌​ntity.EntityFramework‌​). Do you have that referenced in your service project?

Comment: I have this issue - the NuGet package manager says it's installed for the Services project but I don't see it listed in References